# EF Core 3.1 - Database scalar function - string.Join

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, user-defined-functions, user-defined-types, ef-core-3.1

Since `string.Join(...)` is not translatable in the latest EF Core and a lot of our queries do use that method, I'm currently trying to implement it with user-defined functions. I can see that the function actually works in the ssms but I can't get it to work in c#.

The method needs to accept an array of strings as an input so I created a user-defined table type:

```
IF TYPE_ID('[system].[stringList]') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TYPE system.stringList AS TABLE (val nvarchar(max))
    END
GO
```

Then I created the function itself:

```
create function toCommaSeparatedString(@strings [system].[stringList] readonly)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    DECLARE @values nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @values = COALESCE(@values + ', ', '') + [val]
    FROM @strings
    return @values
end
```

I can verify that it works by simply executing the following sql in the ssms:

```
declare @input [system].[stringList]
insert into @input values ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4')
select dbo.toCommaSeparatedString(@input)
```

In c# I declared the function on my DbContext (I tried both `string[]` and `IEnumerable<string>`):

```
[DbFunction("toCommaSeparatedString", "dbo")]
public static string ToCommaSeparatedString(string[] strings) => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

And used it:

```
...
var output = MyDbContext.ToCommaSeparatedString(new [] { "1", "2" });
...
```

but I'm getting an exception:
`"The parameter 'strings' for the DbFunction 'BusinessUnitDbContext.ToCommaSeparatedString' has an invalid type 'string[]'. Ensure the parameter type can be mapped by the current provider.",`

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve here? Should I also configure that function on the DbContext?

EDIT:
Here is my custom projection that i want to use to create the viewmodel:

```
private static IQueryable<IView> ProjectToJobOverView(this IQueryable<Job> entities)
{
    return entities.Select(j => new JobOverView
    {
        Id = j.EntityId,
        Deleted = j.Deleted.HasValue,
        Name = j.Name,
        Status = j.Status.ToString(),
        NumberOfInstructionSets = j.Tasks.Count(t => t.InstructionSet != null),
        NumberOfCompletedInstructionSets = j.Tasks.Count(t => t.InstructionSet.IsCompleted),
        NumberOfOrderLines = j.Tasks
                            .SelectMany(t => t.TaskOrderLines).Select(x => x.OrderLineId)
                            .Distinct()
                            .Count(),
        Details = j.Tasks
            .OfType<StockMovementTask>()
            .Where(t => t.InstructionSet != null)
            .Select(t => t.InstructionSet)
            .Select(s => new JobOverviewDetail
            {
                Id = s.EntityId,
                Deleted = s.Deleted.HasValue,
                State = s.Tasks.First().OperationState.ToString(),

                DeliveryMethod = BusinessUnitDbContext.ToCommaSeparatedString(
                    s.Tasks
                        .First()
                        .TaskOrderLines.Where(x => x.OrderLine.Order is OutgoingOrder && (x.OrderLine.Order as OutgoingOrder).DeliveryType != null)
                        .Select(x => (x.OrderLine.Order as OutgoingOrder).DeliveryType.Name).ToArray()),
            }),
        Categories = j.Tasks.Select(t => t.Process.ProcessDefinition.ProcessDefinitionGroup.ProcessDefinitionCategory.ToString()).Distinct().ToArray(),
        OrderNumbers = j.Tasks.OfType<StockMovementTask>().SelectMany(t => t.TaskOrderLines).Select(j => j.OrderLine.Order.Number).Distinct().ToArray(),
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not just run String.Join on the client?

Comment: Client evaluation is not acceptable due to its low performance.

Comment: So how are you planning to use the concatenated strings on the server?

Comment: My goal is to create a viewmodel with sql query. I've got an array of db entities and a custom projection (just something like: entities.Select(e => new JobView {...}) and it can get VERY complicated and we want it to be done by sql server). We want to get a pure viewmodel-related sql query. I know how to work around this by just fetching these strings as an array and later on iterate over the results and do the string.join on the client side but that's not the purpose.

Comment: But why not just get the Entities from SQL Server before performing the string concatenation?  Why do you think that would perform poorly?  And have you considered asking for JSON and having SQL Server produce the serialized view model directly?

Comment: Well, I'm sure it wouldn't be that bad to iterate over generated views and just use string.join on some properties but this is the workaround i already have. What I want to do is to use efcore's magic in order to keep everything in one place (sql) and not do the foreach after fetching entities from the database. The thing that we are considering right now is getting user-defined functions to work. If this is technically impossible, then we'll think about other solutions or workarounds. So the question stays open - is this technically possible? Because if it is, it will always perform better.

Comment: Fair enough.  One last ask.  Add an example of how you would ideally like write a LINQ query that creates your view model.

Comment: I edited the question and added the exact projection. It already contains the call to BusinessUnitDbContext.ToCommaSeparatedString(...).

Comment: hi @Aranha have u found a solution for this?

Comment: hey @JustinFlores no we have not found any solution, we simply went for doing this in the memory